# Frozen flask creates the files but gets the links wrong

Tags: python, flask

Using frozen flask to make my website static, I have the following problem.

While all of my pages *are* being built (`file//c:/correctpath/build/2014/page-title/index.html`) the links to the pages are `file:///c:/2014/page-title/`.

Is there something I have missed?

**EDIT**:
In my template I have something like

```
 {% for page in pages %}

             <a href="{{ page.url() }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
 {% endfor %}
```

where `.url()` is a method on the `page` object:

```
return url_for('article', name=self.name, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

`url_for` produces absolute paths (e. g. `/2014/page-title`) - when you open up your files in the browser it follows [the rules regarding relative URL resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5) and strips the extra file contents.  If you just want to view your files as they will be seen on the server, Flask-Frozen has a [`run` method](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#testing-url-generators) that will let you preview your site after generating it.

Alternately, you can [set `FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS` to `True`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#configuration) to have Flask-Frozen generate links with `index.html` in them explicitly.

Comment: I already have the `FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS = True`. I have other `url_for` that in the frozen product gets turned into a path like `/tag/food/index.html` and not `/tag/food/`. I thinks is pretty strange that there is this inconsistency. I can get it working with `freezer.run(Debug=True)`, however it seems to require some webserver rule that knows what `/article/title` should map to.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting `FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS = True`, with resulting URLs ending on `index.html`, you can also set [`FREEZER_BASE_URL`](http://pythonhosted.org/Frozen-Flask/#configuration) to `<http://your.website/subdir>`.